# Get maximum value of grouped by departments using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I'm trying to view the maximum salary from the table **ORG** grouped by *DEPT* .Below is my table data I've created using Oracle SQL

[image]

I've used the query to group and display DEPT and total salary as shown below where I got the grouped department and its's corresponding total salary

**QUERY** :SELECT DEPT,SUM(SALARY) FROM ORG GROUP BY DEPT;

**RESULT** :

[image]

But I'm expecting the result only to display the maximum value of the above 
ie., 2 | HW | 113000 .Can you pls help to modify the above query..Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need only 1 row from your aggregated query you can use subquery to get it.

```
SQL> select * 
2 from (
3       select dept,SUM(salary) sum_salary 
4       from org 
5       group by dept
6       order by sum_salary desc
7      )
8 where rownum <= 1

DEPT       SUM_SALARY
---------- ---------- 
  HW       113000
```

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want the whole row, not an aggregation.  So, use a `where` clause, in this case, with a correlated subquery:

```
select o.*
from org o
where o.salary = (select max(o2.salary) from org o2 where o2.dept = o.dept);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is already close to the solution. You need only get the row with the maximum value for salary:

```
WITH SUMSAL AS (SELECT DEPT, SUM(SALARY) AS SAL FROM ORG GROUP BY DEPT)
SELECT * FROM SUMSAL 
WHERE SAL = (SELECT MAX(SAL) FROM SUMSAL)
```

This may give you more than one row, if there is more than one department having the maximum sum of salaries.

Comment: @Radim Bača, no this works well when there is more than one dept